# NHibernate - Could not find file hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: nhibernate

I have hibernate.cfg.xml included in my WCF service library with

```
BuildAction = Content and   
Copy to output directory = Copy Always
```

However, when I run the application it is throwing following error:

```
Could not find file
'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 2010.2\IDETools\System\CodeRush\Bin\PlugIns\hibernate.cfg.xml'
```

I am not sure why it is looking for hibernate.cfg.xml at above path instead of run-time bin directory.

FYI: I have recently installed DevExpress v10.2 to be used in another application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option is to move your nHibernate configuration into the web.config

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In your `configsections` section add

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" requirePermission="false" />
    ...
  <configSections>
<configuration>
```

Another option is to try this (untested in wcf)

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanks Rippo, setting Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; solved my problem. However I am still not able to understand why runtime is having DevExpress as current directory.

Comment: Pass on that however it is always better to explicitly tell the  NHibernate configuration where to find the config xml.

Comment: Using a WCF Service Application rather than a library, I found that I needed to prefix "bin/" to the filename. Since the assemblies will be in the bin folder upon deployment anyway, I reckon that this kind of hard-coding will not be a problem.